# Why my cat loves to drink ice cold cow milk and is it safe to offer so?

Tags: cats, feeding, diseases

My cat generally doesn't drink any milk. But she loves to drink ice cold cow milk.

So my question is why is it so? And is it safe to offer so? Note that there is very little chance of food infection for milk not being boiled as it is treated pasteurized packet milk from reputable company.

Other than lactose intolerancy I want to know whether there is any chance of toncilitis on giving my cat ice cold milk?